# What is the meaning of string argument in django model's Field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

Just learning django, I'm reading [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models) and getting confused at this part:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Having searching its documentation, still can't figure out what does `'date published'` argument mean? Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well here is an example of what human-readable name means.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Enter published date')
```

[image]

So in our admin panel we see our **pub_date** feild name as **Enter published date**.

But if you try to fetch data from database you will see the feild name as **pub_date**.

```
>>> data_dict = Question.objects.all().values()
>>> data_dict
[{'question_text': u'What is Python?', 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 22, 12, 23, 42, tzinfo=<UTC>), u'id': 1}]
```

Comment: I see, so the string argument is used as label string in view.

Answer (score 10):

Because this feature is hard to find in the documentation, I think it's better practice to explicitly use the [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) argument, e.g.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date published')
```

Answer (score 7):

From that exact tutorial page you linked to, about three paragraphs down:

> You can use an optional first positional argument to a Field to designate a human-readable name. That’s used in a couple of introspective parts of Django, and it doubles as documentation.